# |Fri Jul 30 20:53:33 2010] |error] |client {IP}] Premature end of script headers: /home/siteroot/public_html/power/fckeditor/test.php

Tags: php, apache, server-error

A problem has been reported to me that uploading through fckEditor will not work. After messing about with some settings it turns out that running php files in the fckEditor folder will not work and an Error 500 is returned. When I checked the log files the message in the subject was returned. The script is simple:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

When I run this script from power/test.php, it works. It's only when running scripts from any folder within fckEditor/ that doesn't work.

I am using php 5.2.9 and Apache 1.3.42.

Comment: What script errors out?  Where's the code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted.

I thought this would be down to permissions so I gave everything 777 thinking that would account for everything. It turns out I gave to many permissions, directories need 755 and files need 644.

Hope this helps someone else.